# A stronger version of Cauchy integral theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

I have learnt the "normal" Cauchy integral theorem that if a function $f$ is holomorphic in an open set that contains a simple closed piece-wise smooth curve $\Gamma$ and its interior, then $\displaystyle\int_{\Gamma}f(z)\mathrm{d}z=0$.

But our teacher asks us to prove a stronger version: Suppose that $\Gamma\subset\mathbb{C}$ is a rectifiable simple closed curve and $\Omega$ is its interior. $f$ is continuous in $\overline{\Omega}$ and holomorphic in $\Omega$, then $\displaystyle\int_{\Gamma}f(z)\mathrm{d}z=0$.

I manage to prove it when $\Omega$ is a star domain, but fail to generalize this conclusion. Also, I know this question is trivial if I am allowed to use Mergeylan's theorem directly. But Mergeylan's theorem is too advanced for us because we have only been studying complex analysis for a month! I know this question have been posted many times on mathstackexchange, but I wonder if there is any more elementary proof. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Both versions are imprecise. Define intetrior of $\Gamma$.

Answer (score 0):

Boils down to compare growth of partions of the area with countour integrals over all the boundaries of a  say small rectangles by Stokes theorem to the area $$\int_{\partial V} f(z) dz = \int_  V \partial_{\overline z}f(z) \ d\overline z \wedge dz  =0$$ by Cauchy-Riemann equations.

Check convergence for any series of countour inside converging to the rectifiable limiting contour with normal distance dr   length of contour and mean of f.